# laravel css styling based on if statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to figure out how I can apply different css styling to my index.blade.php page depending on whether the $category is active.

I.e If there is no category specified in the url then the image would be small and if there was a category in the url the image would be large.

Route.php

```
Route::get('blog/{category}', ['as' => 'blog.category', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getCategory']);
```

blogcontroller.php

```
public function getCategory($category = null)
{
    // get all the blog stuff from database
    // if a category was passed, use that
    // if no category, get all posts
    if ($category)
        $posts = Post::where(function($query) use($category){
                    $query->where('category','=',  $category );
           }) ->get();

    else
        $posts = Post::all();



    // show the view with blog posts (app/views/blog.blade.php)
    return View::make('blog.index')
        ->with('posts', $posts);
}
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

<h2>{{ $post->id }}</h2>
<h2>{{ $post->img }}</h2>
<p>{{ $post->name }}</p>
<p>{{ $post->category }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
return View::make('blog.index')
        ->with('posts', $posts);
```

into:

```
return View::make('blog.index')
        ->with('posts', $posts)
        ->with('category', $category);
```

And now in Blade:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<h2>{{ $post->id }}</h2>
<h2>
@if (is_null($category))
{{ $post->img }} - here somehow you need to display small image using image width/height or thumbnail
@else
{{ $post->img }}
@endif
</h2>
<p>{{ $post->name }}</p>
<p>{{ $post->category }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried this but get syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('. <?php if: ?> (is_null($category)

Comment: @tomharrison There was one ')` missing. I've corrected it

Answer (score 0):

If your css is internal css so you can use the below method:

```
<style>

@if(your condition)

.container-wizard {

    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
  
    
}
@else

.container-wizard {

width:83%;
position: relative;
margin: 20 auto;


}


 @endif

</style>
```

If your css is external you can use the same method by reference links:

```
@if(your condition)
  <link href="/assets/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

@else

  <link href="/assets/vendor/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

@endif
```

Moreover for your category you can add flag.